# Can't hook up usb wifi Realtek RTL8211, Ubuntu 20.04, Dedicated, Old Win HP Pavillion Destop

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

similarly with Ubuntu 20.04 On HP Vista Destop converted to Linux I had a working linksys wifi doggle '>broke and now have difficulty installing a Blue Shadow Doggle on  "r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RTL8168c/8111c, 00:1f:c6:6f:f8:f9, XID 3c2, IRQ 24"
I tried several other Doggles without success > "Linksys Wusb6300" & 'TP-Link AC1200*
I ran  "dmesg -w" and those are some results but I am virtual newbie, and attacking Linux with a vengeance as windows/computers are my Nemesis. Comprehension and apprehension difficulties associated with product compatibilities. I have other problems: syntax, so...  sorry,  Nvidia, Optical reader... But 1 problem at a time

Realtek Card reader ?> r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RTL8168c/8111c

robin@caribou:~$ lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0111 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5111 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

robin@caribou:~$ lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 02)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 92)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801IR (ICH9R) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 Communication controller: Conexant Systems, Inc. HSF 56k Data/Fax Modem
01:05.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): LSI Corporation FW322/323 [TrueFire] 1394a Controller (rev 70)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)
05:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 High Definition Audio Controller [GeForce 940MX] (rev a1)
```

Comment: 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC <-- This is your wireless device. The required driver is 88x2bu. Please see the duplicate. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.